# File Input Element on change GWT client side

Tags: java, file, gwt, input, client

I'm making a client side only app in GWT that uses WebGL to apply post processing effects to an image. I have added a `InputElement` to the document of type file like this.

```
InputElement inputElement = InputElement.as(Document.get().createFileInputElement());
inputElement.setAccept("image/*");
Document.get().getBody().appendChild(inputElement);
```

Then I wanted to add an onchange listener to it, and since that is not supported in GWT, I wrote this JSNI method to do that.

```
private native void registerOnChange(Main object, InputElement element) /*-{
    if (!$wnd.update)
        $wnd.update = $entry(object.@com.shc.cartoonizer.client.Main::updateImage(*)(element));

    element.onchange = $wnd.update;
}-*/;
```

The issue is, this is throwing a JS TypeError on file change. This is the error that is thrown in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    apply_0_g$           @ Impl.java:247
    entry0_0_g$          @ Impl.java:306
    (anonymous function) @ Impl.java:72
```

Is there anything mistake I'm doing?

Comment: Reason for downvote please? I'm expecting to add an onchange listener on the file input element, but I don't understand why this error is getting thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $entry(object.@com.shc.cartoonizer.client.Main::updateImage(*)(element))
> ```

`$entry` takes a function as input and returns a function, but you pass the result of the `updateImage` function.

Because `$entry` calls `apply` on the passed-in function, and your `updateImage` probably has a `void` return type (which means the function in JS will implicitly return `undefined`), you get a `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` error.

The solution is to pass to `$entry` a function that will call `updateImage`:

```
$entry(function() {
  object.@com.shc.cartoonizer.client.Main::updateImage(*)(element);
})
```

That being said, is there any reason you don't use a `FileUpload` widget and `addChangeHandler`?

Comment: The reason I'm not using a FileUpload widget is because I don't have a server to upload the file to. My server is a static server which just serves only static HTML pages.

Comment: A `FileUpload` widget is just an `<input type=file>`, so that's not a good reason for not using it.